# Start a windows service without elevation

Tags: service, elevated-privileges

I have a windows service "Service1" configured to log on as "Local Service".

I built a console application to start it programmatically.

```
        var service = new ServiceController("Service1");
        service.Start();
```

I know that if I run the ConsoleApplication1 from an administrator command prompt it starts smoothly.

And if I run it without elevation I get an:

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

But, **I need to start it without elevation**.

Is it possible, or I have to change the way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I wasn't clear. It's exactly a programming issue.
I'm trying to start a service from a C# WPF application, but I need to do it without elevation.

Comment: I've also found a solution, if you reopen the question I can share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed torak [link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx) and I understand this key difference concerning rights in a service:

- a service has rights concerning the "Run as" user
- a service has different permission to control the service (i.e. to start/stop it)

So, to start the service I need to modify the service control permission.

Well, I have done a windows service called Service1 and I made an installer with WIX.
During setup I call [ServiceInstall](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm)

```
      <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"
       Name="Service1" DisplayName="Service1"
       Description="Service1 description"Start="demand"
       Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
       ErrorControl="ignore" Interactive="no" >
      </ServiceInstall>
```

Then I have a client program called TestProgram where I try to start the service:

```
var service = new ServiceController("Service1");
service.Start();
```

And obviously it doesn't start the service without elevation of TestProgram (that runs under a normal user account).

So the solution is to instruct WIX to allow members of the user group (for example) to start/stop the service, using the [PermissionEx](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_permissionex.htm) tag:

```
<util:PermissionEx User="Users" ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes">
</util:PermissionEx>
```

Hope this helps. Thank you all.

Comment: Great answer. Some additions: 1. Put `<util:PremissionEx>` tag inside `<ServiceInstall>` (WiX documentation doesn't list it as a valid parent, it's a bug in the WiX documentation). 2. Don't forget to add *util* namespace declaration into `Wix` tag (at the very top of WiX file): `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"`.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the ACL for the service itself to allow this. The [SetACL.exe utility](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/) makes this (somewhat) straightforward; e.g.:

```
SetACL.exe -on "MyService" -ot srv -actn ace -ace "n:S-1-5-32-545;p:start_stop"
```

This allows members of the Users group (S-1-5-32-545) to start and stop MyService.

Comment: Whoops!  Didn't work for me.  In an elevated prompt the command ran OK.  Service "MySQL".  I chose the "Administrators" group.  Tried (in a non-elevated prompt): fail: "StartService: OpenService FAILED 5: Access is denied".  Reboot.  Try again: same fail.

Comment: If you use `S-1-5-32-545`, this means Administrators and you must run elevated.

Comment: Thanks... elevated again: this time I got the following fail: "Processing ACL of: <MySQL> / SetACL finished with error(s): / SetACL error message: The call to SetNamedSecurityInfo() failed / Operating system error message: Access is denied"

Comment: Sorry; don't know what's happening on your system. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

If i can add my 2 cents,  here is my solution that wont require any complex App.Manifest or Windows Service modification.

The concept is simply to call "**Net Start**" through a process that is elevated :

```
public string StartServiceViaProcess(string param_strServiceName)
    {
        try
        {
            const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223; //The operation was canceled by the user.

            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C net start " + param_strServiceName;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            try
            {
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_CANCELLED)
                    return "L'usager a annulé la demande d'exécution avec privilège.";
                else
                    throw;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.SI_ConvertToString();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it - It is my understanding that this is due to security reasons. Allowing malware to automatically elevate itself would be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://woshub.com/set-permissions-on-windows-service/) is the link that I followed and solved my issue.

> **How to Grant non-Administrators Rights to Manage Services**
>
> By default, common users with no system administrator privileges
>   cannot manage Windows services. It means that they cannot stop, start
>   or change the settings or permissions for such services. In some
>   cases, it is necessary that a user had the permissions to restart or
>   manage certain services. In this article, we’ll consider some ways to
>   manage permissions for Windows services. In particular, we’ll show how
>   to grant a standard user without administrative rights the permissions
>   to start and stop a specific service...
>
> There is no simple and convenient integrated tool to manage services
>   permissions in Windows. We’ll consider some ways to grant a user
>   permissions to manage service...